# Haskell finding the correct number in list

Tags: list, haskell, compression

So I want to put in two parameters into this function, a list and the position of the item that I want to print.

```
listNumber [1,2,3,4,5,6] 2
>> 3
```

I have tried this problem by doing this

```
numberList :: (List a) => a -> a -> a
numberList a b = [x | x <- a !! n, n <- b]
```

I don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but your code doesn't have a single mistake--really, the whole thing is wrong in multiple ways. You should consider working through the first few chapters of [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) to get the hang of the language before trying to ask specific questions about it.

Comment: More constructively, could you explain each expression in your code and what you think it does?  That would give people an opportunity to discuss.

Comment: Well what we put in x is 'a' which is the n'th number, which is determined from n which we get from b

Comment: Let's start with the type signature, does `a -> a -> a` make sense when you're taking in 2 different things (a list of stuff and a number) and then returning an item from the list? Try `[a] -> Int -> a` Read as `[a]` as *a list of a's*

Comment: Ok if you replace that then how would you declare it on the 2nd line `numberList [a] b ......`?

Comment: Also would you have to do `y <- b` or could you just do `numberList [a] b = [x | x <- [a], [a] !! b]` if even legal?

Comment: Try writing `numberList a n = a !! n` without a type signature and loading it in ghci or hugs, then play with it. Do `:t numberList` to find out what type you get.

Comment: I didn't think it would be so simple to just do it like that. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an interesting way of going about it.
If we ignore the type signature for the moment and look at the function:

```
numberList a b = [x | x <- a !! n, n <- b]
```

we see that n is called in the first condition of the list-comprehension:

```
x <- a !! n
```

but n is only defined after that, in the second condition:

```
n <- b
```

This leads to an error:  Not in scope: `n'

So the first thing to do might be to switch the first and second conditions:

```
numberList a b = [x | n <- b, x <- a !! n]
```

Now asking GHCi about the type, we get:

```
Prelude> :t numberList
numberList :: [[t]] -> [Int] -> [t]
```

GHC expects parameter a to be a list of lists and parameter b to be a list of ints. This is because n is drawn from b and anything on the right side of <- in a list comprehension must be a list. Since n is used as a parameter for !!, GHC assumes that n is an int and b is a list of ints. 
Now GHC assumes that x is also coming from some kind of list. So we know that GHC assumes a !! n is a list. But since by definition, a !! n is the element of list a at position n, we see why GHC assumes a is a list of lists -- because GHC assumes the element of list a at position n is the list from which x is drawn.

Here's a working example:

```
Prelude> numberList [[1,2,3,4,5,6]] [0]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Here GHC indeed shows us the element of list a at position 0, which is the list [1..6]. Unfortunately, this does not allow us to conveniently get at the positions inside the list, as we would like. An alternate way to still use a list comprehension may be to define a new list 'c' that contains the element we are after (a !! n) and draw x from this new list, like so:

```
Prelude> let numberList a b = [x | n <- b, let c = [a !! n], x <- c]
Prelude> numberList [1,2,3,4,5,6,3] [2]
[3]
```

It seems a bit convoluted, though, since we can simply use !! to get the element of a at position b directly:

```
Prelude> let numberList a b = a !! b
Prelude> numberList [1,2,3,4,5,6] 2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

> So I want to put in two parameters into this function, a list and the position of the item that I want to print.

```
>>> listNumber [1,2,3,4,5,6] 2
3
```

Okay. Step one: you have a really messed up type signature.

```
numberList :: (List a) => a -> a -> a
```

This should not be ignored. Starting with a good type signature is an essential skill for mastering good programming technique in Haskell and similar languages.

First, you want a function with two inputs.

```
numberList :: a -> b -> c
```

Next, you want the first input to be "a list." We don't know what this list contains, so we'll just use a type parameter `a`. The way to write "a list of `a`" is `[a]`.

```
numberList :: [a] -> b -> c
```

You want the second input to be "the position." This will probably be an `Int`.

```
numberList :: [a] -> Int -> c
```

Finally, you want the result to be an element of the list. So it will therefore have the same type `a`.

```
numberList :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

I have no idea where you got that `(List a) =>` part of the type signature, but it's totally bogus, unless you are using some custom library that you're not telling us about. This is quite possible if you are taking a university course on Haskell.

We have a type signature, and it might be handy to know if this has already been implemented for us. Stop! Hoogle time. Enter the type signature `[a] -> Int -> a` into http://haskell.org/hoogle . It turns out that you are trying to implement `!!`.